# Odoo14: Send an email through code using a recordset in the template

Tags: email, odoo

Using a scheduled task, I need to send an email which will inform on the status of open tasks. After getting the recordset correponding to my search, I found how to load the template and send the email:

```
mail_template = self.env.ref('test_email.email_template')
mail_template.send_mail(self.id)
```

But I only got access to the current record in $object. I would like to be able to pass the recordset to the template and loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the context to "transport" data into the mail rendering:

```py
mail_template.with_context(my_recordset=my_recordset).send_mail(self.id)
```

In your mail template just use `ctx`:

```html
%for record in ctx.get('my_recordset', []):
<div>${record.my_attribute}</div>
%endfor
```